# Error: There are no arguments to 'out_of_range' that depend on a template parameter

Tags: c++, exception, throw

i'm trying to throw an exception on a class member like this:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename Object>
Object& ArrayList<Object>::operator[](size_t index) 
{
    if (index >= _size)
        throw out_of_range("Index out of range");

    return arr[index];
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
In file included from array_list_tests.cpp:4:
array_list.h: In member function 'Object& ArrayList<Object>::operator[](size_t)':
array_list.h:125:15: error: there are no arguments to 'out_of_range' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'out_of_range' must be available [-fpermissive]
         throw out_of_range("Index out of range");
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Same error when you qualify with `std::`, i.e. `std::out_of_range`?

Comment: .. and what @lubgr said: `out_of_range` lives in `std::` and after making up the missing minimal-complete bits, it compiles fine for me (with `std::` inserted in the right spot).

Comment: Yeah @AdriaandeGroot I forgot the std::, would you like to add a answer?